# Cannot find module 'gulp-favicons'

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, favicon

Using [this](https://github.com/haydenbleasel/favicons) plugin, I'm trying to run the following gulp task:

```
var favicons = require("gulp-favicons"),
    gutil = require("gulp-util");

gulp.task('favicons', function () {
    return gulp.src('./images/favicon.png').pipe(favicons({
        appName: 'My App',
        appDescription: 'This is my application',
        developerName: 'Hayden Bleasel',
        developerURL: 'http://haydenbleasel.com/',
        background: '#020307',
        path: './images/',
        url: 'http://haydenbleasel.com/',
        display: 'standalone',
        orientation: 'portrait',
        start_url: '/?homescreen=1',
        version: 1.0,
        logging: true,
        online: true,
        html: 'favicons.html',
        pipeHTML: true,
        replace: true
    }))
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./images/favicons/'));
});
```

But am getting the following error: `Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-favicons'`

The plugin docs state I should be using Node 4.x or above. I am using `v7.7.1`. Any ideas why I'm getting this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : 
favicons = require('favicons')

Here is the document for further read [FaviconGithub](https://github.com/haydenbleasel/favicons)

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work. The docs say to do `favicons = require("gulp-favicons"),`

Comment: did you tried var favicons = require('gulp-favicons/es5');

Comment: For me 
favicons = require('favicons')  worked.

check your npm version and node version, I have added a screenshot showing both on my machine, I tried ("gulp-favicon") and it gave same errors as yours, but changing it to ("favicon") worked

Comment: I think if you omit `favicons = require('favicons')` in your example, your task will run either way.

Comment: that's true, but I have not removed it in which case gulp goes and get the reference for favicon, you can see when I had "gulp-favicon" it gave me an error but not when I had favicon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137588/discussion-between-ralph-david-abernathy-and-knitesh).